# WPF - Apply IValueConverter for collection binding

Tags: c#, wpf, collections, ivalueconverter

In my WPF application I have classes Student and StudentDB.

```
class StudentDB
{
   int StudentId{get;set;}
   string  Name{get;set;}
   string  City{get;set;}
   DateTimeOffset BirthDate{get;set;}
}

class Student
{
   int StudentId{get;set;}
   string  Name{get;set;}
   string  City{get;set;}
   DateTime BirthDate{get;set;}
}
```

The main difference between two classes is the datatype of the Birthday property. one is `DateTime` and another one is `DateTimeOffset`.

Im having following code in my application.

```
IEnumerable<StudentDB> StudentDbs = GetAllStudentFromDB();
IEnumerable<Student> Students = new IEnumerable<Student> Students();
```

**XAML:**

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Students, Mode=TwoWay}" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
```

I need to display the list of student in the DataGrid. 
I cannot bind the StudentDbs since it has a `DateTimeOffset` type property.

To solve above issue I need to apply a `Value Converter`, which will convert `StudentDb` object to `Student` object.

I know how to implement IValueConverter interface I. But i don't know how to apply it for a collection.

Can anyone suggest me a solution to solve this?

Comment: Maybe you can try something similar to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7635319/752842)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You no need a value converter.

The better way is to convert `StudentDB` to `Student` via LINQ or in the other way in ViewModel and then bind collection of `Student` objects to your `DataGrid`.

```
IEnumerable<StudentDB> StudentDbs = GetAllStudentFromDB();
IEnumerable<Student> Students = new StudentDbs.Select(student => ConvertToDto(student));

private Student ConvertToDto(StudentDB)
{
    return new Student 
    { 
        StudentId = StudentId, 
        Name = Name, 
        City = City, 
        BirthDate = BirthDate.DateTime 
    };
}

<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Students, Mode=TwoWay}" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
```

Also it's better to use [`ObservableCollection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx) to prevent memory leaks and allow collection changes.

Comment: @Hi Vadim, Actually I'm using DataServiceCollection<T> (Odata Service) to get list of student from db. So how can i save the changed data (in datagrid) back to database in MVVM way?

Comment: @Rahul it depends on many factors for example 1. what ORM do you use. 2. Do you have 2-tiers or 3-tiers app? 3. Do you add/remove items or just change already existed items.
Also, it's primary opinion based. Typical I'm using ViewModel-layer, service-layer and data access layer. Service layer contains business logic then it can has StudentsService with UpdateStudents(IEnumeralbe<Student> students) method. Business logic will compare DTO with entities and save changes with repository methods.

Comment: I'm using EF and its a 3 tier app. I need to perform crud operations.

Comment: Well in 3-tier app you'll have different entities passed to the client and received back. Then you'll need to attach entities manually each time. Yo can read more info [on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx), [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550218/attach-collections-in-entity-framework), [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/576330/Attaching-detached-POCO-to-EF-DbContext-simple-and) and [SO again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20451461/save-detached-entity-in-entity-framework-6).

Answer (score 1):

Answer for your primary requirement : DateTimeOffset class has a property called **DateTime** that represents the date and time of the current System.DateTimeOffset object. So You can still bind StudentDbs as an DataGrid's Itemsource and you can directly bind the **BirthDate.DateTime** property wherever you want inside the DataGrid to achieve your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The value converter musst be applied on the Columns. So set AutoGenerateColumns="False" and add the columns manually:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
<DataGridTextColumn Header="{lex:Loc ...}"
Binding="{Binding StarString, Converter={StaticResource ...}}">
```

When AutoGenerating is true, use the AutoGeneratingColumn Event of the DataGrid. in xaml add:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Students, Mode=TwoWay}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" AutoGeneratingColumn="StartListGrid_OnAutoGeneratingColumn"
```

In the code behind add something like:

```
private void StartListGrid_OnAutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "BirthDate" && e.Column is DataGridTextColumn)
        {
            var textColumn = e.Column as DataGridTextColumn;
            textColumn.Binding = new Binding(e.PropertyName)
            {
                Converter = new MyValueConverter();
            };
        }
    }
```

Please note that you are overwriting the Binding.

Comment: I need to generate the columns automatically. Any solution?

Comment: The grid raises an event when creating the column. You could use this event to manually generate the binding in code behind. Check this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903950(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: Ok, So how do you apply value converter?